# Concatenate variable into dynamic SELECT statement in PL/pgSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I want to use a variable in a dynamic `SELECT` statement (that is in an `EXECUTE` statement) like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_factor()
  RETURNS TABLE(factor numeric) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    _query character varying;
    _some_condition integer := 50;
    _result decimal;
BEGIN
    _query := 'SELECT factors.factor_material FROM factors
               WHERE factors.condition = _some_condition;';

    EXECUTE _query INTO _result;

    RETURN QUERY SELECT _result;
END;
```

I have a variable `_some_condition integer := 50;` and I want to concatenate its value into the SELECT statement (`...WHERE factors.condition = _some_condition;`) however this is giving me a "column does no exist" error:

> ```
> ERROR:  column "_some_condition" does not exist
> LINE 1: ...erial WHERE factors.city_id = _some_cond...
>                                          ^
>
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function get_factor() line 12 at EXECUTE statement
> ```

Why am I getting this error and how to fix this? Keep in mind I have to use a dynamic SELECT statement.

Comment: Use `EXECUTE ... USING` to substitute literals. The manual has details and there are numerous examples here on Stack Overflow. For identifiers use the `%I` specifier of the `format` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to pass a ***value*** (which is not the same as a *literal*, btw), all you need is the [**`USING`** clause of the plpgsql `EXECUTE` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN), like [@Craig commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046748/concatenate-variable-into-dynamic-select-statement-in-postgresql#comment51993594_32046748).

While being at it, simplify your function with [**`RETURN QUERY EXECUTE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN60519):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_factor()
  RETURNS TABLE(factor numeric) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _some_condition integer := 50;
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
      'SELECT factor_material
       FROM   factors
       WHERE  condition = $1'
   USING _some_condition;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Nothing in this example requires dynamic SQL. You could just:

```
RETURN QUERY
SELECT f.factor_material
FROM   factors f
WHERE  f.condition = _some_condition;
```